# ObjectIds don't get retrieved from collection (Scala + MongoDB)

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, json4s, objectid

There is a MongoDB instance on my computer with a database. A couple of documents are present in one of the collections, I inserted them manually. There is a Scala application to manipulate the database. There is a case class called Location.

```
case class Location(_id: Option[ObjectId] = None, name: String) {
  var visible: Boolean = false
}
```

This is the MongoDB configuration in the application.

```
private val customCodecs = fromProviders(
  classOf[Location]
)
private val javaCodecs =
    fromCodecs(new LocalDateTimeDateCodec(), new LocalDateDateCodec())

private val codecRegistry =
  fromRegistries(customCodecs, javaCodecs, 
  DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
val dbConnection = MongoClient(dbURI)

val database: MongoDatabase = dbConnection.getDatabase(dbName).withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
```

There are more `classOf` definitions in the `customCodecs`, just removed them. The `dbURI` string is retrieved from a config file.
There is a controller endpoint, which returns all Locations from the database. The result is this:

```
[{"_id":{},"name":"Hungary","visible":false},{"_id":{},"name":"Germany","visible":false},{"_id":{},"name":"France","visible":false},{"_id":{},"name":"Switzerland","visible":false},{"_id":{},"name":"Poland","visible":false}]
```

The documents in the database have ObjectId, since I entered them manually, and some documents should have the `visibility` property true. I suspect there is something wrong with the JSON serialization, but cannot figure it out what.
This is the code which queries the collection.

```
val query = collection.find().toFuture()
Await.result(query, 10.seconds).toList
```

The service method calls this code and passes the result to the controller.

```
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
val languages = enrollmentService.getAllLanguages
    logger.info("GET all languages")
    Ok(Json.parse(write[List[Language]](languages)))
```

I use json4s for JSON serialization / deserialization.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to include org.json4s.mongo.ObjectIdSerializer?

Comment: For some reason, I cannot resolve that. I found that serializer, but cannot import it. I have the latest version of json4s in the project (3.6.4).

Comment: Anyway, I managed to implement a CustomSerializer based on the code from `org.json4s.mongo.ObjectIdSerialize`